# AutoCompleteTextView does not properly display text with ActionBarSherlock theme

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock with the Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar theme and the text in my AutoCompleteTextView is so the same colour as the background.  I have tried calling setTextColour() and passing in the int referring to Black, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Is this a known bug? Or an unknown bug? Or am I just missing something?

Here's a screenshot showing how it looks when selected - which suggests it's not jut a case of being the same colour as the background:

[image: screenshot of the problem - with text selected]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using `getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext()` for inflating the views in your adapter? The action bar context is different than the regular context since the colors are reversed.

Comment: I wasn't, but I just fixed that.  Now the autocomplete drop down text is the right colour (black), but the text in the Text view itself is still the same colour as the background - if that makes sense.

Comment: I've played around with themes with no success.  I've also attached a screenshot so that you can see how it looks with the text selected, suggesting that perhaps it's not an issue with the colour of the text, but simply that the text is invisible...

Comment: OK - based on the clue that you gave me, I've fixed this.  I did what you suggested and it fixed the drop down text, but not the textview text.  Adding Resources res = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext().getResources(); 
  int black = res.getColor(android.R.color.black); and using that int to set the text colour for the autocompletetextview fixed it

Comment: I thought you were putting the `AutoCompleteTextView` inside the action bar. If you aren't then it's an Android bug and doesn't really have anything to do with ABS.

Comment: Bizarrely I'm now seeing that my "fix" only works in gingerbread & lower. In ICS & Jelly Bean (I haven't tried Honeycomb) the text in the field appears in black - but the text in the drop down is still white. Are you sure it's not an issue with the theme in ABS?

Comment: @JakeWharton can you please review question I've asked - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352148/actionbarsherlock-and-custom-textbox-extends-autocompletetextview - I've left an easy way to reproduce the error (validated that it happens with sample project your are shipping with the library). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My issue seems unrelated to ABS. I came across the solution here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237

Using android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line instead of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 worked for me in all Android versions.

Comment: THANK YOU! You truly saved me with this piece of advice! Just have you run into this same problem while extending existing controls (like extends EditText)? If yes, how have you solved it? If no - thanks again for your existing answer!