# ActionBarSherlock and custom TextBox (extends AutoCompleteTextView)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

OK, I'm going crazy over this - I've integrated ActionBarSherlock in my app and am using Theme.Sherlock. Now, I can't seem to get my custom textbox to work properly - whenever I leave textbox, text becomes white. Here is image to better explain the problem (I've used Overlay layout from examples that come with the library):

Typing:

[image: Step 1 - Typing]

Going back to EditText:

[image: Step 2 - Going back EditText]

Does anyone have idea why this is happening?

**EDIT:** To reproduce this error simply download the ActionBar zip and extract sample project. Then in that project in Overlay layout (res/layout/overlay.xml) in first LinearLayout just add:

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
<AutoCompleteTextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And run sample project on device with older version of Android OS.

Comment: I've just tried with extending EditText instead of AutoCompleteTextView and everything works with 0 problems. Also, I've saw the link to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237 on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392613/autocompletetextview-does-not-properly-display-text-with-actionbarsherlock-theme?rq=1) and now I don't know whether I need to blame ActionBarSherlock for the bug or it's the bug within Android.

The important thing is - does anybody have idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237#c8)? It appears to solve your issue :)

Comment: Yeah, tried it - no luck :(. Basically I just need foreground color for AutoCompleteTextBox ( - but the one that would take into account that on older devices text should be black and on 3.0+ devices it should be white (and that on some custom made devices it maybe should be pink) - then I would just supply that value in my custom control's constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now I get it why nobody was able to answer this - it seems to happen only on specific devices! So, in my case I was reproducing it on old Amazon Kindle.

The current workaround I finally found, that works for me, is to set textColor of my control by getting textColor of default EditText (yeah, pretty ugly).

If someone has better idea - do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

- What are the minimum and target SDK versions?
- Which theme are you using with your application/activity?

Extend that default theme you are using and define the text colors there. See [Inheritance](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance)